# Как передать файл от TClientSocket к TServerSocket

Tags: c++builder, c++

Здравствуйте!
Как мне реализовать передачу файла от клиента к серверу?
Есть пример передачи файла от сервера к клиенту. [вот ссылка](http://www.sources.ru/magazine/1204/tsocket.html)
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Эмм... Берете код, который отвечает за прием файла на клиенте и код который отвечает за отправку на сервере... Ну.. и грубо-говоря меняете местами. Подправите имена переменных и комильфо.

Comment: Это уже делал он что то не принимает. Ошибок не выдает, но и файла в папке Downloads, а в мемо заносит бред место текста.

Comment: Проблема решена!
Спасибо за ваши ответы.